# FHIR app: how to make a call against some api endpoint

Tags: api, endpoint, hl7-fhir

This is the github repository URL to add codes of calling FHIR apis.
https://github.com/cerner/smart-on-fhir-tutorial

I have created am app by following steps in this tutorial.
And now I need to insert some codes to call this endpoint : fhir.cerner.com/dstu2/medication-statement/

Is it possible to call 'POST' api in Sandbox?
If yes, how to do it? This is what I want to know.
Hope to learn from you about this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi! Please show us the code you have so far, and the error or faulty result you get when running it. It helps to give us a minimal example of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I think you could see entire codes here: https://github.com/cerner/smart-on-fhir-tutorial
example-smart-app/src/js/example-smart-app.js
And this js file contains codes related with API calls.
There is no error actually, and what I want to do is to add calls of API `medication-statement.`
Hope this to help you understand my trouble..

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your query is unsuccessful is because the URL you are calling is invalid. Cerner's open sandbox environment for DSTU2 (and R4) are documented [here](https://fhir.cerner.com/millennium/dstu2/#service-root-url) and [here](https://fhir.cerner.com/millennium/r4/#service-root-url). To call the MedicationStatement resource you would need to use this base URL:

https://fhir-open.sandboxcerner.com/dstu2/0b8a0111-e8e6-4c26-a91c-5069cbc6b1ca/MedicationStatement

The above URL is the open endpoint which does not require authentication. The authenticated endpoint (to perform create and update operations) is:

https://fhir-ehr.sandboxcerner.com/dstu2/0b8a0111-e8e6-4c26-a91c-5069cbc6b1ca/MedicationStatement

All functionality for a FHIR server can be discovered by using the metadata endpoint. Cerner's is:

https://fhir-ehr.sandboxcerner.com/dstu2/0b8a0111-e8e6-4c26-a91c-5069cbc6b1ca/metadata

Cerner does support several POST operations (including MedicationStatement)